# htmlspecialchars (against xss) breaks URL

Tags: php, url, encoding, xss, htmlspecialchars

I looked over multiple posts but couldn't find the solution.

I want to add htmlspecialchars over $_SERVER variables on the following code to prevent from XSS.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "'.htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']).htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).'";</script>';
```

The problem is that the function breaks the URL by escaping quotes and ampersand

On similar topics, some users suggested using urlencode instead of htmlspecialchars, but urlencode is not meant to prevent xss on the HTML code above.

Comment: You should use `urlencode()` for URL's. `htmlentities()` isn't meant to be used on URL's. Are you simply trying to reload the page you're on (since you're using the server variables)? In that case, just do: `location.reload();`. Also, HTTP_HOST won't contain the schema.

Comment: How about sending this URL as an ajax response? But first of all, what kind of web page are you opening through this?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks for your response Magnus. Yes, the goal is to reload the same page. But how will i prevent from XSS if i use urlencode ? anybody could inject a <script></script> on the URL and a malicious code will be loaded on the 'echo' above...

Comment: You tagged me in your comment, but you didn't write anything??

Comment: _“anybody could inject a <script></script> on the URL”_ - and what would `urlencode` make out of such input …?

Comment: _“The problem is that the function breaks the URL by escaping quotes and ampersand”_ - explain what you actually mean by that, give a proper example of what exactly goes wrong, with what input data.

Comment: If you do: `location.reload();`. it will reload the page you're on. There's no need to escape anything or build the URL yourself. The browser already have the URL and will reuse the same if you use `reload()`. If you feel that you need to escape the URL here, it's already too late (since the client is already there).

Comment: Could you not just use `str_replace()` and replace `&quot;` with `"` and `&amp;` with `&` after using `htmlspecialchars()`?

Answer (score 2):

Your example puts the value in JavaScript, not in HTML. The thing with XSS protection is that there is no one-size-fits-all. You need to adjust your approach based on the context you output to.

For JavaScript it is JSON. You need to encode your value as JSON and output it to JavaScript. Because JSON is a subset of JavaScript, you can just output it as-is without quotes or further escaping.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = '.
    json_encode($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).
    ';</script>';
```